# Transfer MongoDB to another server?

Tags: mongodb

If I populate a MongoDB instance on my local machine, can I wholesale transfer that database to a server and have it work without too much effort?
The reason I ask is that my server is currently an Amazon EC2 Micro instance and I need to put LOTS of data into a MongoDB and don't think I can spare the transactions and bandwidth on the EC2 instance.

Comment: It's never a good thing when you ask a question on SO and 5 minutes later you google for your tags and the first item is your brand new question on SO.....

Comment: That's why I usually google first. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is [copy database](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands) command which I guess should be good fit for your need.

Alternatively, you can just stop MongoDb, copy the database files to another server and run an instance of MongoDb there.

Comment: where's the (common) location of database files you mentioned?

Comment: @akhyar The location of database files specified when you run mongodb instance.

Comment: Do you need to copy /journal too, or just the databasename.X files?

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation how to specify another instance (port) on the same server.